# Regex pattern appearing infinite times

Tags: objective-c, regex

I'm looking for the regex pattern of three spaces followed by any sequence of numbers followed by a period and then a space. I have achieved almost this result, except that my regex doesn't allow for any number of numbers, just one number:

```
NSRange range = [newString rangeOfString:@"  [0-9]\\. " options:NSRegularExpressionSearch];
```

How can I make it detect any number of numbers 0-9?

Comment: Will there be more than one occurrence in the string? As in, could your string contain more than one match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
@" {3}[0-9]+\\. "
```

**Explanation**:

```
 {3}            # ' ' (3 times)
[0-9]+          # any character of: '0' to '9' (1 or more times)
\.              # '.'
                # ' '
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the + quantifier after the character class

```
@"  [0-9]+\\. "
```

Also MJB noted that your regex, as posted, only shows two spaces at the beginning.  Was there an error in your regex?  Or in your description?

Comment: @MJB I just copied and pasted from the OP's regex, where he said the only problem was the number of digits.  But you are correct in that there are only two spaces.  I'll note that in my answer.